# How i can remove space between integer between brakets in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a problem i want to submit it on online judge it want me to print the result in co-ordinates x,y like

```
print (2,3)
(2, 3) # i want to remove this space between the , and 3 to be accepted
# i want it like that
(2,3)
```

i make it with c++ but i want python i challenge my friends that python make any thing please help me
the whole code of proplem i work on it

```
Bx,By,Dx,Dy=map(int, raw_input().split())
if Bx>Dx:
  Ax=Dx
  Ay=By
  Cx=Bx
  Cy=Dy
  print (Ax,Ay),(Bx,By),(Cx,Cy),(Dx,Dy) #i want this line to remove the comma between them to print like that (Ax,Ay) not that (Ax, Ay) and so on the line
else:
  Ax=Bx
  Ay=Dy
  Cx=Dx
  Cy=By
  print (Ax,Ay),(Dx,Dy),(Cx,Cy),(Bx,By) # this too
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> print "({},{})".format(2,3)
(2,3)
```

your code should be like this:

```
print "({},{})({},{}),({},{}),({},{})".format(Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy)
```

Comment: thank you its work 100% but i have another problem face me i want to remove space between brakets i want the out put like this (0,5)(10,5)(10,0)(0,0) not (0,5)  (10,5)  (10,0)  (0,0) and thank you alot

Comment: just dont give the space while printing

Comment: i write it print "({},{})".format(Ax,Ay),"({},{})".format(Bx,By),"({},{})".format(Cx,Cy),"({},{})".format(Dx,Dy) so i remove space between the number in pracket i want to remove the space between pracket it self and thank you

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the general case, manipulate the string representation.  I've kept this a little too simple, as the last item demonstrates:

```
def print_stripped(item):
    item_str = item.__repr__()
    print item_str.replace(', ', ',')

tuple1 = (2, 3)
tuple2 = (2, ('a', 3), "hello")
tuple3 = (2, "this, will, lose some spaces", False)

print_stripped(tuple1)
print_stripped(tuple2)
print_stripped(tuple3)
```

My space removal is a little too simple; here's the output

```
(2,3)
(2,('a',3),'hello')
(2,'this,will,lose some spaces',False)
```

Answer (score -3):

"Strip" the tuple whitespace with  listcomprehension;

```
tuple_ = (2, 3)
tuple_ = [i[0] for i in tuple]

in function

def strip_tuple(tuple_):
   return [i[0] for i in tuple_]
```

Comment: Did you forget something?  This is not syntactically legal.

Comment: yep, there's a strip() that should be included but can't find where at the moment, pardon,